# How EV chargers know the battery's charge level?

Tags: electric-vehicle

I know charging station generates 1kHz PWM to set charging current - even Wikipedia has nice explanation how to use it. But that is only communication protocol I can find. I did notice some charging stations can provide vehicle's information - like state of charge. What communication protocol is used? How? I read some use CP and PE pins - where could I find information about how to read the EV's SoC?

There is ISO 15118, which seems to use WiFi? Which would be the right way to read info from EV?

Comment: EVs don't use WiFi to communicate with the chargers, that's done using ISO 15118 along the charging cable. But the chargers may use WiFi or mobile data to communicate with the wider charging network or power company to determine tariffs, optimum time of day to charge etc.

Comment: Do you more information about how this communication through cable is done? What signals, etc. are used?

Answer (score 1):

> How EV chargers know the battery's charge level?

EVC chargers do not know or care about the battery's SoC. All they know is the power of the AC going to the vehicle. Only the vehicle knows the SoC.

> I know charging station generates 1kHz PWM to set charging current

That tells me that you're specifically referring to a J1772 charging station. That is but one of many standards. I tailored my answer to the J1772 standard.

> some charging stations can provide vehicle's information - like state of charge.

That would be information that the vehicle volunteered wirelessly (possibly on the Internet), and the charging station go from it. Not through the charging cable.